# React/VITE: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to get firebase wired up to my react/vite app.

I have a file called `firebase-config.ts` which does this:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs, doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: "x",
  projectId: "x",
  storageBucket: "x",
  messagingSenderId: "x",
  appId: "x",
  measurementId: "x",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Realtime Database and get a reference to the service
const db = getFirestore(app);

// get a reference to a collection
const myCollection = collection(db, 'myCollection');

// create a document reference
const myDocument = doc(myCollection, 'myDocument');


// write data to the document
setDoc(myDocument, {
  title: 'My Document',
  content: 'This is my first document.'
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('Document written successfully!');
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error writing document: ', error);
});
```

And i am trying to initialise it in the `Main()`` component of my react app (the top most component):

```
import React from "react";
import "./db/firebase-config";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Auth from "./Auth";
import "./index.css";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  [...]
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

When I attempt to use `firebase-authentication` (on a seperate component) to handle registration I get this error:

```
Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app).
```

I thought I was calling that from the TS file?